# UIView rotate problem

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have two UIViewController in my app. I switch the view between them. One is hidden other one is not. Everything goes fine except the orientation problem. In both UIViewController 
I override this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
    //return YES;
}
```

and set orientation to landscape in both Xib files.

in ***Delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions    
{
   .......
   viewController.view.hidden=TRUE;

   [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];

   [self.window addSubview:menuController.view];

   .....
}
```

if I add viewController.view first viewController.view is landscape position and it can rotate to landscapeLeft or landscapeRight. But the menuController.view is still portrait position and the view cannot rotate at all.

if I add menuController.view first the situation is opposite.

Why this happened? How to fix this? My app is almost done. Is there any simple way to solve this problem without make big changes to my code.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Which view controller is being defined as the rootViewController for Window? When the device rotates, AFAIK, the view that is manipulated is the one at `rootViewController.view`.

You can check this putting an NSLog in each view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. If I'm right, you'll see only one call to this function.

Define which view controller should be the root, and present the other one modally, or use a navigation controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To: Gonzalo Larralde           Thanks a loooot. I'm kind of understanding what are you saying . There is no rootViewController define in my app. So I tried your way. menuController is defined as rootViewController and viewController is add to menuController.view as a subview.  the menuController is showed as what I'm expected however the viewController.view just become blank. Or I should add viewController to menuController class as an instance instead of adding both controller to the Delegate. In this way I may need to change a lot of my code that's not I want.

Comment: How should it work? menuController AND viewController should be visible at the same time? In that case, specify which of those views is the main view controller, the view controller that should always remain visible. In this case, I would define a view/scroll view inside the menuView reserved to the main view controller, and then, inside the menuController, define and instantiate the viewController and add it's view there.

Comment: Only one view need to be visible at one time.  My code in delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:{.......
viewController.view.hidden=TRUE;[self.window setRootViewController:menuController];
 [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];}

Comment: The hidden property will be changed during switching the view

Comment: and it works now? or it's showing the viewController.view blank? Have you tried instantiating the viewController inside menuController?

Comment: No, viewController still showing blank. Ok, I'll try put viewController inside menuController. In this way I need to change a lot of code. This is my very first app. Thank you for your great help.  I'll update if this works.

Comment: I didn't put viewController inside menuController yet. But find another thing. The orientation is not manipulated by the rootViewController. Even I set the menuController to the rootViewController it's still in portrait position if I add viewController.view to the window as subview first. So the orientation is manipulated by the first subview of the window. Is there any easy way to force each UIViewController to call shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html    this article explain my problem. Looks like there no other way to fix except the parent-child viewcontroller way.